# To make a face hidden in edit mode remain hidden in object mode What should I do?

Tags: materials, edit-mode

To make a face hidden in edit mode remain hidden in object mode
What should I do?
After hiding the face in Face edit
When viewed in object mode, the hidden face reappears.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you can use a Mask modifier for example if you want to hide a face (you'll need to inset the face though)

Comment: the question is: why don't you just delete it?

Comment: @Chris -- ya'll forgetting about the Mask mod?!

Comment: I need to look inside the object

Answer (score 2):

The Mask modifier should be perfect for your needs, Except that you have to assign the vertices you want to hide to one or more vertex groups. In this example I assign top, middle and bottom vertex groups on a sphere.   Note that instead of assigning a (default) Weight of 1.0, I assigned 0.5, as you'll see can be useful in animation.

[image]

I then use one or more mask modifiers that have different modes (mask all except in VG (invert selection), or mask VG.  One can then also use the slider that will mask or not depending on GT or LT vertex weight.

[image]

One could assign differing weights to various vertices in a group so that parts of the object slowly appear/disappear.  Try the slider for "middle", for example.

Note: the mask modifier will hide *faces* that are defined by a vertex to be Masked, so you may have not the exact same vertices in a group as you might expect... experiment.

I also include the monkey mesh with similar to try out. [image]

Comment: wow thank you so much

Comment: @GKCC -- it would be so kind if you could click on the check mark top left of my answer.  I gain reputation points that lead me to answer questions!